# How to slow down Cassandra node?

Tags: performance, cassandra

I'm doing a kind of performance testing and I need to slow down Cassandra node. What is the best practice to achieve this kind of task?

I was looking into Compaction Strategy, but I think it isn't what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create slowness in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666858/how-to-create-slowness-in-cassandra)

Comment: want random pauses or just to increase latency overall?

Comment: I want to increase latency overall.